# How can I convert a for loop into Stream and break it in the middle?

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda, java-stream

How can I convert the following piece of code into stream format, tried filter, foreach and map but still something is wrong.

```java
private Status validate(final Type type, final String id) {
    for(Validator validator : validators) {
        Status status = validator.validate(type, id);

        if (status == Status.INVALID || status == Status.VALID) {
            return status;
        }
    }

    return Status.UNKNOWN;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this loop down. You first go over all the validators and call `validate` - that's a `map` operation. If the `status` is `INVALID` or `VALID`, you return it - that's a `filter` operation with `findFirst` logic. And if you can't find one, you return `UNKNOWN` - that's an `orElse` operation. Putting it all together:

```java
private Status validate(final Type type, final String id) {
    return validators.stream()
                     .map(v -> v.validate(type, id))
                     .filter(s -> s == Status.INVALID || s == Status.VALID)
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElse(Status.UNKNOWN);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got stuck in all of filter, map and stuff